# Can I configure bash to execute "clear" before every command typed in the console?

Tags: bash, terminal, prompt, console

I would like to configure bash to execute `clear` command every time I type some command in the terminal (before executing my command). How can I do that?

I'm using Debian Linux.

Comment: You find [this](http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) thread useful.

Comment: Just curious:  What's you application for this? Except when I'm debugging programs with a lot of output, I usually want to keep as much as possible on the screen to help me keep track of the context I'm working in.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Bash has a precommand hook](http://glyf.livejournal.com/63106.html). Sort of.

```
preexec () {
  clear
}
preexec_invoke_exec () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return                     # do nothing if completing
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # don't cause a preexec for $PROMPT_COMMAND
    local this_command=`history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g"`; # obtain the command from the history, removing the history number at the beginning
    preexec "$this_command"
}
trap 'preexec_invoke_exec' DEBUG
```

Comment: Gilles: I pasted the above into a konsole terminal and the output from each command I subsequently entered got cleared before I could read it.  Am I missing something?  Also, what happens for this (and the other answer below) if I invoke a multi-line bash script where more than one line (or any line other than the last one) generates interesting output?

Comment: @Joe This should clear the screen after you press `Enter`, before executing the command. It works like this for me. The preexec hook is executed for each interactive command, it doesn't matter whether the command is a built-in or an external command or many commands.

Comment: @Joe you need to add this line bellow do nothing if complete       `[ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return;` the problem is that PROMPT_COMMAND is being run and also trapped after the actual command; Also Can some one tell me why      `local this_command=\`history 1 | sed -e "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g"\`;`
is here?

Comment: @JamesAndino `history -1` prints the last command line, with a history number in front. The sed filter strips off the history number.

Comment: @JamesAndino That made it work (and I see Giles added it to his answer.)

Comment: Just for completeness, trap '' debug turns this thing off again (two single quotes).

Comment: isn't $PS4 a fairly effective *preexec* hook in any shell?

Answer (score 6):

```
bind 'RETURN: "\e[1~clear; \e[4~\n"'
```

After that every time you press <kbd>return</kbd> instead of just writing `\n` it will move to the beginning of line, enter the text `clear;`, then move to the end and enter `\n` as it expected.

Comment: A newline causes the prompt to be printed anyways, so putting the clear in the prompt accomplishes the same thing *without* polluting the command history with `clear` commands.

Comment: @jw013 The difference is that in my case `clear` is executed before the command and command output doesn't disappear. However in case with prompt it does.

Comment: I wish there were some way to do this without having to modify the command line itself - I'm sure this would break in interesting ways on complex or multi-line commands but I can't find any better way to do this.

Comment: @jw013, you are right, it does break for multi-lines.. It inserts `clear;` to the output for each extra `\n`.

Comment: this tip is very good thx!! I needed to bind some specific code to F2, but some times the line has some command I typed but not executed, so with this ex.: `bind "\"\\eOQ\":\"\e[1~ls;#\\n\""` it will move to the beginning, type `ls;#` commenting what was there, and run the `ls` command properly! thx!

Answer (score 3):

from a question I asked today (with credit to user [@aecolley's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180745/72456)) :

```
bind '"\C-m": "\C-l\C-j"'
```

The `\C-m` simulating the 'Enter' key, the `\C-l` simulating `Ctrl+l` as it's clear and the `\C-j` is "newline-and-indent", so the command is binding Enter key to Ctrl+l & Ctrl+j

that works on GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14) and the other answers on this thread do not. also, this does not pollute history with 'clear' commands every other command.

Comment: note: if using over ssh, you must execute it in that environment or weirdness happens.

Comment: greate it works on my ubuntu 16.04 terminal, thanks
but how does it work, could you provide a link or some documentation please?

Answer (score 1):

## Consider only clearing when you want to

```
cb4() {
  preexec () {
    clear
  }
}
```

This uses a hook called `preexec`, confirmed works with zsh too

Then any session you want to automatically clear before every command you run: `cb4`

## If you are certain you always want to clear in every context

```
preexec () {
  clear
}
```

## And a if you actually want to reset the terminal

replace the word `clear` with `tput reset`

`tput` is optional but speeds up the reset process

Comment: Can you please explain what the role of `cb4` is? Is it a built-in name or something you came up with, what does it do, is it something like a “scoped” configuration/named session? Thanks

Comment: @DavidWolf The hook is called preexec,  I called my function cb4, call it whatever you want. You are calling a method that calls the hook which runs clear after every command you run (making your command at the top of your terminal window which I wanted at the time for something specific, your usage may vary). But if you open a new terminal then that will not clear automatically, that would require running the command cb4 again. That is intentional, so you only call cb4 once when you know after every command following it you want that behavior.

Comment: As an alternative to the currently accepted answer which if you had in your .zshrc or similar would run all the time which you might not actually want.

Comment: Wonderful. By calling the function the hook is registered, now I understand – thanks a lot @jasonleonhard

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad to be of service.