# How to execute 'clear' bash command before any other command is executed?

Tags: bash

I see the question at [Can I configure bash to execute "clear" before every command typed in the console?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44713/can-i-configure-bash-to-execute-clear-before-every-command-typed-in-the-consol), but the answers there are not valid for GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14). The problem with the answers given there is that the output of the command gets cleared before it can be read. That is a pretty popular bash version as it is released on mac os X. I cannot comment on the best answer there due to lack of rep points so my only option is to ask a new question.

The reason for wanting this functionality is that many commands i use (such as 'git status') have multi-line output. When multi-line commands are run back-to-back, it is not very easy to automatically separate the blobs of text on the screen.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this functionality on the version of bash specified?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I configure bash to execute "clear" before every command typed in the console?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44713/can-i-configure-bash-to-execute-clear-before-every-command-typed-in-the-consol)

Comment: not a duplicate. the accepted answers there don't work on a common platform (os x). i would comment on the answers, but i don't have the necessary rep. only option was to ask another question.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant That is a really strange close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way. It assumes you have the default key bindings.

```
bind '"\C-m": "\C-l\C-j"'
```

The `\C-m` intercepts the 'Enter' key, the `\C-l` (`Ctrl+L`) executes the Bash `clear-screen` function, and the `\C-j` executes the Bash `newline-and-indent` function; so the command is binding Enter key to Ctrl+L & Ctrl+J

Comment: works for me, thanks! note: if using over ssh, you must also execute in that environment.