# Catch and decorate each command before execution

Tags: bash

I need to intercept each command I type on the command line, such that I can *decorate* them.

For example, whenever I type `echo Hi` what I really want to be executed is `/bin/wrapper "echo Hi"`.

Is there anyway to achieve this in bash, except from recompiling it?

EDIT: Also, `for _ in 1 2; do ping -c1 google.com; done` must become `/bin/wrapper "for _ in 1 2; do ping -c1 google.com; done"`

Comment: the DEBUG trap may be one way to go. "The trap builtin (see Bourne Shell Builtins) allows a DEBUG pseudo-signal specification, similar to EXIT. Commands specified with a DEBUG trap are executed before every simple command, for command, case command, select command, every arithmetic for command, and before the first command executes in a shell function. The DEBUG trap is not inherited by shell functions unless the function has been given the trace attribute or the functrace option has been enabled using the shopt builtin. The extdebug shell option has additional effects on the DEBUG trap."

Comment: example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44723/117549

Comment: Maybe `alias` could be a solution: `alias echo="echo you typed: "`, so `echo here we go` will result in `you typed: here we go`. But I am not sure how it will behave overwriting bash build in commands. And it won't repeat your command this way ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [bash-preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec).

Download the script:

```bsh
wget 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec/master/bash-preexec.sh'
```

Source the script:

```bsh
source 'bash-preexec.sh'
```

Now, according to its [usage notes](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec#usage):

> Two functions **preexec** and **precmd** can now be defined and they'll be automatically invoked by bash-preexec if they exist.
>
> `preexec` Executed just after a command has been read and is about to be executed. The string that the user typed is passed as the first argument.
>
> `precmd` Executed just before each prompt. Equivalent to PROMPT_COMMAND, but more flexible and resilient.

You can use these like so:

```bsh
preexec() { echo "just typed $1"; }

precmd() { echo "printing the prompt"; }
```

It might also be worth mentioning that bash-preexec is just a shell script which is implemented using the `DEBUG` trap and the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable.

For more information about the `DEBUG` trap see the reference documentation for the `trap` command:

- [The Open Group Base Specifications: Chapter 2 - Shell Command Language (trap)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#trap)

For more information about the `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable refer to the Bash manual:

- [Bash Reference Manual: Section 6.9 - Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is achievable in [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/). Zsh is a broadly used shell that uses a language that is pretty much a superset of bash, and designed to have a very customisable UI.

In Zsh, you can define an arbitrary function to to be carried out when you press enter. This can do arbitrary things to the contents of the line. (See the `accept-line` widget). One solutions is therefore to switch to using Zsh.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for a `bash` solution: *"Is there anyway to achieve this in bash, except from recompiling it?"*

Comment: It does. I think explicit is a bit strong since switching from `bash` to `zsh` can be done at very little learning cost, so switching to zsh is a valid solution to the problem. Do you not think it is possible that the person asking this question would be interested to know that this can be achieved by switching to `zsh`? Do you not think that other people would be interested in this? A question always represents a set of assumptions made by the asker about what the best way to solve their problem is. These assumptions may be flexible. As such a little generalising of the problem can be useful.

Comment: Well, it was definitely stated explicitly. That just means that it was stated directly and unambiguously, as opposed to being communicated implicitly (i.e. being implied). If you want keep your solution posted I would consider adding a sentence to acknowledge that you're not answering the question exactly as asked - just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Hmm... so the question is *what* was stated explicitly.

Comment: It sounds like we're miscommunicating, but I'm not sure where. All I'm saying is that the question was specifically about `bash`. The exact words are: *"Is there anyway to achieve this in bash, except from recompiling it?"*

Comment: Yeah... so I what I really mean is that he didn't explicitly say "I only want to do this in bash", I guess I'm reserving my right to read the question slightly more broadly unless explicitly told not to do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69271/discussion-between-igal-and-att-righ).